# Azure function gets AuthorizationFailure when trying to GET a file in Azure Blob Storage that is not public

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

In my Azure function, I am trying to download a file from Blob Storage named `myappbackendfiles`.

Code (`utils/Azure/blobServiceClient.ts`) that initiates the `BlobServiceClient`:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

const account = "myappbackendfiles";
export const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  new DefaultAzureCredential()
);
```

Code that uses the `BlobServiceClient`

```
import { blobServiceClient } from "../utils/Azure/blobServiceClient";

...

    // Create BlobServiceClient
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    // Stream the blob to a local file
    const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
    const blobReadableStream = downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody;

    if (blobReadableStream) {
      const writableStream = fs.createWriteStream(localFilePath);
      blobReadableStream.pipe(writableStream);
    }
```

However, when I test the function in azure function app, I got this error;
and as you can see, it is trying to `GET` the file `https://myappbackendfiles.blob.core.windows.net/issues/src-A/dst-B/2023-08-15-01-52/c1diouasdfhia1231/testFile.zip`

```
{
   "name": "RestError",
   "code": "AuthorizationFailure",
   "statusCode": 403,
   "request": {
      "streamResponseStatusCodes": {},
      "url": "https://myappbackendfiles.blob.core.windows.net/issues/src-A/dst-B/2023-08-15-01-52/c1diouasdfhia1231/testFile.zip",
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
         "_headersMap": {
            "x-ms-version": "REDACTED",
            "accept": "application/xml",
            "user-agent": "azsdk-js-storageblob/12.15.0 (NODE-VERSION v18.16.1; Linux 5.10.177.1-1.cm1)",
            "x-ms-client-request-id": "cca1e0cc-b8f3-49f7-8d50-5de520714f96",
            "x-ms-date": "REDACTED",
            "authorization": "REDACTED"
         }
      },
      "withCredentials": false,
      "timeout": 0,
      "keepAlive": true,
      "decompressResponse": false,
      "requestId": "cca1e0cc-b8f3-49f7-8d50-5de520714f96"
   },
   "details": {
      "errorCode": "AuthorizationFailure",
      "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
      "access-control-expose-headers": "x-ms-request-id,x-ms-client-request-id,x-ms-error-code,Content-Length,Date,Transfer-Encoding",
      "content-length": "246",
      "content-type": "application/xml",
      "date": "Wed, 16 Aug 2023 08:18:07 GMT",
      "server": "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0",
      "x-ms-client-request-id": "cca1e0cc-b8f3-49f7-8d50-5de520714f96",
      "x-ms-request-id": "11d56133-501e-001b-0d1a-d0c60f000000",
      "message": "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:11d56133-501e-001b-0d1a-d0c60f000000\nTime:2023-08-16T08:18:08.0305733Z",
      "code": "AuthorizationFailure"
   },
   "message": "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:11d56133-501e-001b-0d1a-d0c60f000000\nTime:2023-08-16T08:18:08.0305733Z"
}
```

I have done steps that have been suggested by people:

- I have turned on the System Assigned Managed Identity for this function app;
- I have assigned to my Function app the needed roles on the resource `myappbackendfiles`; see the below screenshot. I believe I have done quite some overkill in this regard:
  [image: screeshot]

I have set the storage account networks to "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses". I do not want to enable from all networks since the data is private.

Below are the outbouding IP addresses of the function app:
[image]

And I have added these IP addresses to the "white list":
[image]

However, I am getting the error above.

Now I found out that as soon as I change the Public network access to "Enabled from all networks":
[image]

The error is fixed!  There is no "AuthorizationFailure" anymore.

However, obviously I cannot keep it as "Enabled from all networks".
The private data will leak...

What can I do ?
I must be missing something very basic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your connection string look like?

Comment: Also share if your storage account is behind a firewall or inside a virtual network.

Comment: If your storage connection string contains an access key, ensure that account key access is enabled in the storage account's properties. Alternatively to use the managed identity, you would probably need to use a different function on BlobServiceClient instead of fromConnectionString.

Comment: @juunas Thank you for the answer. I changed to using `DefaultAzureCredential` from the `"@azure/identity"` library to initiate the `BlobServiceClient` object. (See the updated post). However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you very much. I have updated the code (see the post) and in the storage account's network settings I have changed to "Enabled from all networks". It only worked after I changed to "Enabled from all networks". If I want to keep the storage private, what can I do?  Add a firewall exception on the storage with the IP of the function app did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I uploaded a blob in my storage account container at Azure Portal like below,

[image]

Assigned **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to my **function app**,

[image]

Then, I changed the **Networking** access to **Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses** in Azure Storage as shown below,

[image]

I tried below typescript code to download a blob from my storage account container.

**Code:**

```js
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    const containerName = "<container_name>"; 
    const blobName = "<blob_name>"; 

    try {
        const connectionString = process.env["AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING"];
        if (!connectionString) {
            throw Error("Azure Storage connection string not found in configuration");
        }

        const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

        const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

        const blobDownloadResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
        const blobReadableStream = blobDownloadResponse.readableStreamBody;

        const headers = {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain", 
            "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename="${blobName}"`,
        };

        context.res = {
            status: 200, 
            body: "Blob downloaded successfully!", 
            headers: headers,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        context.log.error("An error occurred:", error);
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: "Internal Server Error",
        };
    }
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

**.env** :

I added the storage account connection string to the **.env** file like below,

```js
AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account_name>;AccountKey=<account_key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

With the above **URL**, the **blob downloaded successfully in the browser** like below,

[image]

Then, I deployed this code to my function app and it deployed successfully as below,

[image]

I have set the **storage account connection string** in **Configuration** section in the function app,

[image]

I run this **function** in **function app** at **Azure portal** and it runs successfully as below,

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In the step where you changed the Netwoking access to `Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses`, how did you get the IP range or IP address of the Function App?

Comment: Is your function app in a VNet / subnet?

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C The above IP is a default IP generated in storage, it's not a function app IP.